# Makefile - wrong sequence of compiling

Tags: c, makefile

In makefile below I'm trying to compile one directory, but make against my will is trying to do it in wrong order. It's starting from compiling main.o and later it goes straight to compiling console. I have no idea why it's not trying to solve all dependences before it. I just get:

```
user@ubuntu:~/Dokumenty/Sysopy/cw1/zad3b$ make 
gcc -c -Wall -I ./src/include src/main.c 
gcc  -o macierze main.o 
main.o: In function `main': 
main.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `wczytaj' 
main.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `wczytaj' 
main.c:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `suma' 
...
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [console] Błąd 1
```

Here's a makefile:

```
############ makra #############
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -I ./src/include
LFLAGS = 
VPATH = ./src/operacje: ./src/we_wy: ./src/reszta

########### pliki ##############
SRC_CONSOLE = wczytaj_konsola.c wypisz_konsola.c
SRC_FILE        = wczytaj_plik.c wypisz_plik.c pliki.c
SRC_FUNCTION    = suma.c roznica.c iloczyn.c macierz.c
HEADERS     = suma.h roznica.h iloczyn.h wypisz.h wczytaj.h macierz.h
OBJ_SONSOLE = $(SRC_CONSOLE:.c=.o)
OBJ_FILE    = $(SRC_FILE:.c=.o)
OBJ_FUNCTION    = $(SRC_FUNCTIONS:.c=.o)


console: $(OBJ_CONSOLE) $(OBJ_FUNCTION) main.o 
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o macierze $^

file: $(OBJ_FILE) $(OBJ_FUNCTION) main.o
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o macierze $^ 

console_logs: $(OBJ_CONSOLE) $(OBJ_FUNCTION) main.o
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o macierze $^

file_logs: $(OBJ_FILE) $(OBJ_FUNCTION) main.o
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o macierze $^

############# objekty ##############
main.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) src/main.c

$(OBJ_CONSOLE): $(SRC_CONSOLE) 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^

$(OBJ_FILE): $(SRC_FILE) 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^

$(OBJ_FUNCTION): $(SRC_FUNCTION) 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^



%logs   : LFLAGS += -D KOMUNIKATY
file%   : LFLAGS += -D PLIKI

./PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f ./src/include/*.gch
    rm -f macierze
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you write  : OBJ_FUNCTION    = $(SRC_FUNCTIONS:.c=.o)
instead of :  OBJ_FUNCTION    = $(SRC_FUNCTION:.c=.o)

and

OBJ_SONSOLE = $(SRC_CONSOLE:.c=.o)
instead of OBJ_CONSOLE = $(SRC_CONSOLE:.c=.o)

Comment: It was just this and next mistake on OBJ_SONSOLE.

Comment: Always run _make_ with `--warn-undefined-variables`.